Ivo Lah's original paper on Lah numbers
Ivo Lah is a slovenian mathematican mostly known for introducing Lah numbers
$$
L(n,k) = \left\lfloor n \atop k \right\rfloor := \binom{n-1}{k-1}\frac{n!}{k!}.
$$
His original paper on this subject has the reference

Lah, Ivo (1954). "A new kind of numbers and its application in the actuarial mathematics". Boletim do Instituto dos Actuários Portugueses. 9: 7–15.

The problem is that I cannot find a copy of it. It is not free of access, behind a paywall nor on SciHub.
On the website of the journal, it is written that boletim 1 through 39 are accessible only to board members of the institute, and that they exists only in paper form...
We can also see on the website that Lah's paper is in boletim 10. As the journal probably was published in paper form (someone must have read Lah's paper to name the numbers he introduced after him), I wondered if anyone had a copy of it and if a pdf scan could be provided. Also, does anyone know who first coined the term Lah numbers and where?

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number we can find very interesting properties of Lah numbers  as well as many references sequences OEIS included.

This is not what I asked.

I can imagine that wood-paneled library in which the board members drink their port and smoke their cigars not even knowing of the gem you are desperately after. Joking aside: the WP article by @Piquito contains a few references that were seemingly written by experts in recent years. I would approach those authors by email if they could kindly share a copy of Lah's original paper.
